# Sorting alphanumeric Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures, jupyter-notebook

My plot in y-axis is set in 1, 11, 12, etc... I would like it to be  1,2,3,4 ... 10, 11

---

```
df = pd.read_csv("numerical_subset_cleaned.csv",                
              names=["age","fnlwgt","educational-num","capital-gain","capital-loss","hours-per-week"])

sns.set_style("darkgrid")
bubble_plot(df,x = 'age', y = 'educational-num', fontsize=16, figsize=(15,10), normalization_by_all = True)
```

---

My `df.info()`:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 32420 entries, 0.0 to string
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------           --------------  ----- 
 0   age              32420 non-null  object
 1   fnlwgt           32420 non-null  object
 2   educational-num  32420 non-null  object
 3   capital-gain     32420 non-null  object
 4   capital-loss     32420 non-null  object
 5   hours-per-week   32420 non-null  object
dtypes: object(6)
memory usage: 1.7+ MB[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Presumably the numbers are stored as strings. You need to convert them back to `int`.

Comment: @Stef is correct, your dtype for all column is `object` which is roughly equivalent to default class type in python. You should convert your numeric columns using `astype`  : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html